# How should I represent a 100k item sparse matrix in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sparse-matrix

I'm writing an algorithm which needs a sparse matrix to store its data. I'll need to store around 100k items into the table, which makes me unsure about many of the recommended solutions, such as using hashes where the key are the coordinates.

What would be an optimal solution in .NET?

Comment: It all depends on the operations that you want to perform on this matrix.

Comment: In your algorithm, is the number of element access operations greater than the number of element modification operations?

Comment: The matrix is being used to first store the data, and then I traverse some of its elements like a graph and modify them in place. This way I have to traverse all of the elements in the matrix.

Comment: Have you gone through [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/673055/Generic-Sparse-Array-and-Sparse-Matrices-in-Csharp)?

Comment: The obvious Google query here is "c# sparse matrix library".  89,000 hits ought to be enough, you don't need another one.

Comment: When you say a 100k item sparse matrix, do you mean that the range of items is 100k, or that there are 100k items over a very large range? What is the range of your data?

Comment: @HansPassant Just because something can be googled it doesn't mean you can't ask it on SO. The point of SO is to get a correct answer, which most of the ones on Google aren't.

Comment: You've made no effort to explain why those 89,000 hits were not good enough to solve your problem.  That leaves us with no reasonable guess at a helpful answer.  Or what "correct" might mean, apparently something else than what is already covered by all of those existing web pages.  This is of course why you didn't get an answer in the past 4 hours, hopefully this is obvious.